# WSLITE: Building JSON REST Request from Map causes StackOverflowError

Tags: json, rest, groovy, http-post, rest-client

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now. Couldn't find any solution so far. 
Basicall I am doing nothing out of the ordinary. 
I have a Method to configure and send a Rest Request using Wslite and this method accepts a map as payload to the closure of the clients' post method like this:

```
    def postSomething(Map payload){

    RESTClient client  = new RESTClient("http://somedomain.com/path/")

    return client.post( accept: ContentType.ANY,
                        headers: [  callTreeId: uuid, jwt: token ] )
                    {
                        json payload
                    }

}
```

The passed map comes from another class which is responsible for some transformation and building the map containing the data I want to post.

The maps is structured like this:

```
    Map data = 
    [
        country: "String1",
        fulfillingStoreId: "String2",
        customerId: "String3",
        cardholderId: "String3",
        deliveryDate: "String4",
        deliveryAddressId: "String5",
        serviceType: "String6",
        paymentType: "String1",
        source: "String7", 
        origin: 
            [
                system: "String8", 
                id: "String9"
            ]
        ,

        contactFirstName: "String10",
        contactLastName: "String11",
        contactPhoneNumber: "String12",

        items: [m_itemList] //a list that holds instances of some item objects

    ]


    def List <Item> m_itemList = []


    class Item {
        def porperty1 = ""
        def porperty2 = ""
        def porperty3 = ""
    }
```

Using `JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(data))` prints a nice Json string representation to the console - everything looks as expected.

Now, passing 'data" map to the post-closure (the payload) raises a "java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.getNode(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackage(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Package.getPackage(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getPackage(Unknown Source)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1595)
at wslite.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:173)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1590)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:173)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1590)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:173)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1590)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:173)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1590)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:292)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1606)
at wslite.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:173)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1590)
at wslite.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:1012)
...
...
...
```

I understand that the contentbuilder of the wslite client accepts a map and i have done it before with other (simpler) requests. So what might be the problem?

Thank you in advance for your contributions.

UPDATE / WORKAROUND SOLUTION:

So after some digging I figured to just re-slurp the built json with the JsonSlurper before passing it to the content building clossure since the "prettyPrinting" the map shows correct results. Voila! No more StackOverFlow Exception.

I now cunstruct the map using the JsonBuilder and parse the result (String) with the JsonSlurper, finally pass this to WSLITE's content builder.

Comment: What version of WSLITE are you using?

Comment: Version 1.1.2. I switches to 2.0 to see if the problem persists and it does!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. Turns out, my `payload` Map had values in it that were not Strings (they were UUIDs and Enums, which typically auto-`toString()` nicely). When I manually converted the values to Strings, the error went away.

`payload.each { k, v -> payload[k] = v.toString() }`